# Узнать Активность Фрагмента в данный момент

Tags: java, android

Имеется два фрагмента.
Чтобы не накладывался один `listView` на другой, я хочу один удалить, другой поставить и наоборот.
Но перед этим я хотел бы удалить предыдущей фрагмент.
Как правильно узнать,активен ли на данный момент фрагмент?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проверять не нужно. `FragmentManager` всё сделает за вас. Для смены фрагментов в контейнере нужно сделать следующее:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
// или getSupportFragmentManager(), если используете AppCompatActivity
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_layout, new AwesomeFragment(), AwesomeFragment.TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```